# How to install Budgie on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: 15.04

I used many guides, and even an offical repo, but all of them result in this

E: Unable to locate package budgie-desktop

I also tried building it myself, but that resulted in this.

make: *** No rule to make target 'install'.  Stop.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential gnome-common gobject-introspection libglib2.0-dev libgtk-3-dev libpulse-dev libpulse-mainloop-glib0 libmutter-dev libwnck-3-dev libupower-glib-dev libgnome-menu-3-dev libc6-dev
git clone https://github.com/evolve-os/budgie-desktop.git
cd budgie-desktop
./autogen.sh
make 
sudo make install
```

Or try with PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:evolve-os/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install budgie-desktop
```

from:[blog](http://media-opensource.blogspot.com/2014/11/how-to-install-budgie-desktop-8-in.html)

Comment: This still happens: "make: *** No rule to make target 'install'. Stop." along with "You should update your 'aclocal.m4' by running aclocal."

Comment: the evolve-os ppa is outdated.

Answer (score 1):

The *official* installation instructions for ubuntu is to build it yourself:

https://wiki.solus-project.com/Budgie_on_other_Operating_Systems

```
sudo apt-get update;sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install build-essential git intltool libtool gobject-introspection libglib2.0-dev libgtk-3-dev libpulse-dev libmutter-dev
sudo apt-get install libwnck-3-dev libupower-glib-dev libgnome-menu-3-dev libpeas-dev uuid-dev valac libgnome-desktop-3-dev
sudo apt-get install gnome-session --no-install-recommends

git clone https://github.com/solus-project/budgie-desktop.git
cd budgie-desktop
./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr;
make
sudo make install
```

But fossfreedom has packages for the latest ubuntu:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fossfreedom/budgie-desktop
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install budgie-desktop
```

Read about [in their blog](https://xpressubuntu.wordpress.com/2015/12/31/installing-the-solus-budgie-desktop-on-ubuntu/)

Be warned, though. Budgie still lacks the following in Ubuntu:

- Network management
- Power management (shutdown etc)
- Volume and sound management

Answer (score 0):

For me under Ubuntu 15.10 desktop amd64 works this:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential gnome-common glibglib2.0-dev libgtk-3-dev libpulse-dev libpulse-mainloop-glib0 libmutter-dev libwnck-3-dev libupower-glib-dev libgnome-menu-3-dev libc6-dev

sudo apt-get install gtk-doc-tools valac uuid-dev libuuid1 uuid-runtime libpeas-1.0-0 libpeas-dev libgnome-desktop-3-dev language-pack-gnome-en-base libpolkit-gobject-1-0 libpolkit-gobject-1-dev libpolkit-agent-1-0 libpolkit-agent-1-dev

make -j8

sudo make install
```